# What is GeneralKey used for in MultiLocation for XCM?

Tags: parachain, xcm, xcmp

Could you explain what is [GeneralKey](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/8b9f5808a401dbf995f4f13b5e1a2ccb8df1b7a4/xcm/src/v1/junction.rs#L68) is for in MultiLocation ?

For example:

```
Asset Name: Karura Native Token 
Asset Symbol:  KAR
Decimals:  12
existentialDeposit: 0.1
Multiloaction: { parents: 1, interior: { X2: [ {Parachain: 2000}, {GeneralKey: 0x0080} ]}}
```

Answer (score 3):

> [GeneralKey](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/xcm/src/v1/junction.rs#L68): Usage will vary widely owing to its generality.

So it may have different meanings on different chains. And here, @insipx is right.

Then, you could find the location from the chain state of assets related pallets on other chains.

For example:

**In karura:**
[image]

**In Khala:**
[image]

**In Moonriver:**
[image]

---

For local tokens, it depends on its XCM config: you mentioned
[Kabocha config](https://github.com/kabocha-network/parachain/blob/mainnet-kab-release-v0.2.4/runtime/src/xcm_config.rs#L48), but it seems not right. You could refer to the config of [Darwinia](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-parachain/blob/main/runtime/darwinia-parachain/src/pallets/polkadot_xcm.rs#L33), for Darwinia, its token could be [{parents: 1, X2(Parachain(2105), PalletInstance(5))}](https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia-parachain/blob/main/runtime/darwinia-parachain/src/pallets/polkadot_xcm.rs#L107) relative to other parachains. If this config doesn't have an interior junction, then it would be {parents:1, X1(Parachain(2105))}.

Comment: thanks for this. So in Kabocha parachain which only has one token, do i instead do X1, and no need for general key? https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkabocha.jelliedowl.net#/chainstate

Comment: @Decentration Too long for a comment, so I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks for the update. So for Kabocha {parents:1, X1(Parachain(2113))}

you mention it seems not right? What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you want to use {parents:1, X1(Parachain(2113))}, in the xcm config of Kabocha, the <T> of IsConcrete<T> should be `MultiLocation::here()` rather than `MultiLocation::parent()`

Comment: how can i make it work with the current set up without having to make a runtime upgrade? or are you saying i need to make a runtime upgrade?

Comment: Yeah you need fix it and make a runtime upgrade.

Comment: what if did it this way? X2(Parachain(2113), PalletInstance(10)), would this work or do i still need to make runtime upgrade?

If so i would also need to pr upstream to cumulus, because it would be a bug?

Comment: If you want to use  X2(Parachain(2113), PalletInstance(10)), you should set `T` to {parents: 0, X1(PalletInstance(<Balances as PalletInfoAccess>::index() as u8)) (refer to darwinia-parachain or other parachains), then upgrade the runtime. It's not a bug of cumulus, just a config of your parachain runtime.

Comment: thank you for your input, i really appreciate it.

Comment: substrate-parachain-template has the same as me, should i make PR there to make it like darwinia? could you also exploain what the chain is? and where did you learn about it, are there good docs somewhere?

Comment: No, you shouldn't make PR, it's just an initial template, those who use it will need to adjust it to their needs. And I'm a developer of Darwinia, this is my experience, I don't known where there are good docs.

Answer (score 2):

`GeneralKey` refers to a general index that will be interpreted by the receiving chain to correspond to *something*, generally a Token.

In the example you show, General Key `0x008` is the location of KAR on Karura. When Karura gets an XCM with that MultiLocation, it knows that you want to do something with KAR and not some other token. If you change the `GeneralKey` to something else, Karura will interpet that as corresponding to a different token.

Lets break down the MultiLocation:

`parents: 1` means the chain has one parent, (which is Kusama)

`X2` means there are two junctions from that parent to get to the KAR token

`Parachain: 2000` means the `Karura` parachain, which is assigned `id` 2000

`GeneralKey: 0x0080` is the index of the KAR token on Karura

Comment: thanks. If i want to find what the General Key for the balances on a different parachain, how do i find it? How do i find the location of other things? I'm assuming 0x008 is little endian bytes?

Comment: Each Parachain has their own way of organizing assets. You may have to dig into the code for some of them to find exactly how they classify different types of assets. Generally, however, parachains have an `assetRegistry` pallet that enumerates the assets which are supported and has a storage item that holds metadata along with the location of that asset, and often the name and symbol of the asset too. @Guantong has some example screenshots of this. You should be able to query this data on all the live parachains that have integrated XCM.

Comment: ok great so if the parachain doesnt have some kind of assetRegistry then i only need the one junction X1?

Comment: if the chain only has the native token, it could be a few things. Generally, it's X2(Parachain(ParachainId), PalletInstance(pallet_balances Index)). Like for moonbeam it is X2(Parachain(2004), PalletInstance(10)).